# Why does Reportlab 3.0 save an empty PDF?

Tags: python, reportlab

This program creates a PDF of a small page with a bit of text on it when I use Python 2.7.6, Reportlab 2.5, and Ubuntu 14.04:

```
import os
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.units import mm

c=canvas.Canvas(os.environ['HOME'] + '/Desktop/test.pdf', pagesize=(4*72, 3*72))

tx = c.beginText(3*mm, 65*mm)
tx.setFont('Helvetica', size=20, leading=22)
tx.textLines("klsdjaldkagiwfjkwa")
c.drawText(tx)

c.showPage()
c.save()
```

When I replace Reportlab 2.5 with 3.0, it instead outputs a PDF that is the same size but completely blank. Why?

Comment: Do you have anything else use to test if Reportlab 3.0 is installed correctly?

Comment: @martineau It looks installed at least somewhat correctly to me because it does properly render barcodes, just not regular text.

Comment: Could be a font issue. Also try moving the text near the center of the page and see if you get anything.